# How default view encapsulation works in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

As we know, default view encapsulation for a component in angular application is Emulated,ie

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
```

I really do not understand how it works behind the hood if it is not a shadow dom.

Comment: Hello and welcome! The question is a bit broad and isn't quite a direct "programming" question, but there are a lot of resources to help you if you search around. The Angular docs are always a good place to start! Here's that reference- https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: @OneLunchMan while I totally agree with you, I think that this kind of question is clear enough to be answered, and (without any intention to offense) maybe the OP needs an explanation "for dummies"-ish

Comment: Great point, @trichetriche, thanks for pointing that alternative out!

Comment: @OneLunchMan.. My question is not about how angular handles the styles of component, it is well written in the docs. What I asked is how the dom tree is formed with custom html tags( ie component selectors), if it is not the shadow dom. I have tried searching this but found no good docs. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: It's fine, you were clear from the start. Having a "starting" point from the docs can lead to read "Emulate native scoping" which in a search quickly reveals super in depth articles like so: https://toddmotto.com/emulated-native-shadow-dom-angular-2-view-encapsulation#what-does-this-mean . Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three types of encapsulation in angular

- ViewEncapsulation.Emulated and this is set by default
- ViewEncapsulation.None
- ViewEncapsulation.Native

## Emulated mode

Assume that you have two different components comp-first and comp-second , For example you define in both of them

`<p> Some paragraph </p>`

So if you apply some styling for paragraph in comp-first.css

```
p { 
   color: blue; 
 }
```

and then inspect p element on comp-first.html and look for its styling will find something like this

```
p[_ngcontent-ejo-1] {
  color: blue;
}
```

"_ngcontent-ejo-1" is just a simple key for differentiate such an element from others components elements

## None mode

If you apply this mode to such a component for instance comp-first and then you go and inspect any element it will not provide any attribute like "_ngcontent-ejo-1" to any element , So applying any styling or class it will be provided globally .

## Native mode

This should give the same result as if you are using emulated mode but it comes with Shadow DOM technology in browsers which support it

Comment: why is the emulated mode the default? to ensure compatibility?

Answer (score 5):

When you write

```
<div class="XXX"></div>
```

With the style

```
XXX { color: red; }
```

The compiler will translate it to

```
<div class="XXX" ng_host_c22></div>
```

With the style

```
XXX[ng_host_c22] { color: red; }
```

it simply adds an unique (randomly generated) attribute to your elements and style, to avoid them colluding with other styles.

This means if you declare the class `XXX` in 2 different components, then they will have a different attribute, and not collude.